# How to use Gnome's extensions (silent installation failure)

Tags: 12.10, gnome

I tried asking this in the Unix & Linux stackexchange, but this may be a better place.

I have been trying to install some Gnome extensions from the site `https://extensions.gnome.org`. I get the dialogue asking if I want to install, but after I select yes, it fails silently. This is the behavior using either Firefox or Chromium. I have checked to make sure the `Gnome Shell Integration` plugin is installed and enabled for both Chromium and Firefox.

My operating system in Ubuntu 12.10, and my version of Gnome is 3.6.3.1. I have made sure (using `sudo apt-get update`) that everything is up-to-date. I have tried restarting, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this (or what is a good workaround)?

NOTE: I have the gnome-tweak-tool installed, and it does not show any extensions as installed. There is nothing happening after I confirm that I want to to download the extension.

EDIT: Extensions are now working. I do not know why. Maybe it was restarting. I will mark the below answer as accepted because it gives good information that may help others. I would suggested to anyone in my position just making sure everything is up-to-date, restarting, and then checking every so often to see if it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to install and use the GNOME shell extensions we need the following packages:

- [gnome-shell-extensions](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-shell-extensions) [image: Install gnome-shell-extensions]
- [gnome-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool) [image: Install gnome-tweak-tool]

We can then install extensions by turning the switch on the upper left corner of the [GNOME extensions download page](https://extensions.gnome.org/) to **ON**. Turning this switch to **OFF** will disable the extension.

[image]

Loaded extensions or themes can then be further controlled with the GNOME tweak tool.

[image]

Comment: Right. I know this. I have both things and they are updated. As I state in my question "I get the dialogue asking if I want to install, but after I select yes, it fails silently." This is an excellent answer to a question that wasn't asked...